# Creating bean if module is not present

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have `reporting-api` module that provides utility classes and so on for reporting, besides that also provides `NoOpReportService` that should be created if no other reporting service bean has been created:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(...)
public class ReportServiceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ReportService noOpReportService() {
        return new NoOpReportService ();
    }
}
```

Now i have CORE module that is optional and provides implementation for reporting service:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(...)
public class DefaultReportServiceConfig {

    @Bean
    public ReportService defaultReportService(...) {
        return new DefaultReportServiceImpl(...);
    }

}
```

What i want to achieve: if `reporting-core` module is present in POM `DefaultReportServiceImpl` should be created - that is not problem and default behavior since its `@Configuration`file.

However, if and only if  the `reporting-core` module is not present i want the `NoOpReportService` to be created. I tried to use

```
    @Bean
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean
    public ReportService noOpReportService(...) {
        return new NoOpReportService (...);
    }
```

But this config file is always scanned before `reporting-core` module's config and thus the `NoOpReportService`  is always created.

The `reporting-api` does not have dependency on `reporting-core` module. I dont want to hardcode some condition on specific `ReportService` impementation since user can implement his own `reporting-service` and not use `reporting-core` module but his own.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Have you considered the [ConditionalOnMissingClass](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnMissingClass.html) annotation? Presumably there are classes that won’t be present on the class path if the `reporting-core` module is not in the dependencies.

Comment: @rimesc i did but the configuration from api module is scanned first and thus the bean is always created since condiitonal in the annotation is true at that time